# Response time with sikulixapi

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, sikuli-x

Im using sikulixapi along with JMeter to automate the workflow. In the JMter log I can see the click events logged with following times in milli seconds. What is this times recorded in the logs?

```
    [error] Mouse: not useable (blocked)
```

[log] CLICK on L[1225,1049]@S(0) (538 msec)

```
[log] CLICK on L[1225,1049]@S(0) (123 msec)
```

[log] CLICK on L[1055,441]@S(0) (531 msec)

```
[log] CLICK on L[1210,682]@S(0) (522 msec)
```

[log] CLICK on L[505,593]@S(0) (523 msec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logged time is the time needed to search the image to be clicked.

In the second case it was apparently the same image as in case 1 (same click location, shorter time because it was found in the same place as with the last search before).

RaiMan from SikuliX

Comment: Thank you, Im using the VNC connection from the laptop. So the search time is from the laptop or from the VNC server?

Comment: If VNC connection means the SikuliX provided solution, then the processing is completely done on the laptop. Only the screenshots are received from the server via the VNC connection (time included).